# Как найти функцию обработчик?

Tags: html, javascript, dom

К HTML странице прикреплено десятка полтора разных js файлов. Что можно использовать, чтобы быстро находить необходимые функции, прикрепленные к конкретному элементу верстки? Нужно узнать имя js файла, в котором она лежит, и желательно строку.

Comment: // зачем к HTML странице прикреплено десятка полтора разных js файлов?...

Т.е. не, я понимаю, что частенько такие штуки достаются в наследство от предыдущего разработчика, но если это ваша архитектура - пересмотрите ее, правда. Как имнимум это сильно гасит скорость загрузки страницы.

Comment: Если обработчики добавлены через `jQuery.click()` и им подобными, то только вручную...

Comment: Зачем к HTML странице прикреплено десятка полтора разных js файлов?  Это портал на SharePoint, там такое нормально. А через FireBug  и тому подобное?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать, есть ли обработчик на теге?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450086/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Это легко делается с помощью хрома:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В Firefox 33 тоже появилась такая [возможность в инструментах разработки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]