# Как узнать, есть ли обработчик на теге?

Tags: javascript

Есть тег. При клике он открывает одну шторку, но я не можу найти обработчик клика на нем в js.

Есть ли какой то способ найти этот оброботчик через инструменты разроботчика?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если речь идет именно об инструментах разработчика, то в Хроме делаем так:

1. Кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по нужному элементу => `Inspect element` (или же F12, а затем находим и выделяем нужный элемент в дереве).
2. Далее в правой нижней колонке есть вкладка `Event Listeners`, там можно найти все обработчики.
3. Соответственно для клика ищем событие `click`.
4. Если необходимо найти только обработчики событий текущего элемента, снимаем галочку `Ancestors`, если же возможно, что клик идет по какому-то родителю (что довольно часто бывает), то галку оставляем.

Answer (score 2):

В **Фаерфоксе** при выборе элемента в **Inspector**-е (правой кнопкой мыши по элементу → `Inspect Element`) справа от тэга появляется маленькая кнопочка **ev**:

[image: Панель разработчика в FireFox]

Answer (score 2):

Я вам рекомендую для этих целей удобный [Visual Event 2](https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2), который визуально показывает на чем стоит обработчик, показывает код обработчика и подсказывает в каком файле прописан этот обработчик.

Его можно как [расширение для Хрома](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim) поставить в браузер, а можно как закладку с горячими клавишами.

Вот пример:

[image: скрин]