# Как определить обработчик события для bootstrap-кнопки (тег a) legacy-кода в отладчике?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, веб-программирование, отладка

Ковыряю достаточно запутанный код сайта, и хочу немного изменить логику работы. Полностью вычитать код проекта и разобратся что там происходит физичиски нереально. пытаюсь в режиме отладки в браузере понять какой конкретно скрипт обрабатывает кнопку, у которой прописаны только классы.

Есть ли быстрые варианты в *Chrome DevTools* или *Firefox* разобратся, какой из скриптов занимается обработкой нажатия кнопки?

Comment: Тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450086/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5 посмотрите