# Есть ли обработчик события Click у элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, click

Подвесил на кнопку *Next* слайдера Slick свой обработчик события Click. Он срабатывает один раз, а потом перестает. Есть подозрение, что это Slick сбрасывает все обработчики, а потом подключает только свои.

Как посмотреть-проверить-вывести (на `JS` или `jQuery`), есть ли в текущий момент у элемента (кнопки Next) обработчики события Click и какие?

Comment: Что вам мешает повесить обработчик на встроенное событие slick'а? $('.your-element').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log(direction);
  // left
});

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450086/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5

Comment: Спасибо, событие «afterChange» как раз подошло! )